# "Global" List (Float)?

Tags: nodes, entities

Assume I have a content type with a  list field (float) that can contain the following values: a, b, c.
I created three nodes (A, B, C) with those field values.

Creating a new node, is there a way to *auto clear/remove* already existing values in older nodes?

For example, if I choose *a* in a new node, I want that in node *A* that value is removed.

The [Unique Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) module does the job of preventing duplicated values, but it doesn't allow to remove values from other nodes.

Comment: what you want to do? you question is not clear. you have a field with 3 choice then ... ?

Comment: See my EDIT please, I think it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: use a field group ([Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group)) of booleans and set them as exclusive values ([Exclusive value](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclusive_value)).